# How to load a trained model from BERTSUM keep facing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.optimizers'

Tags: pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

I trained a model using Bertsum now i want to use it for my task but i keep facing this issue
Bertsum github url:https://github.com/nlpyang/BertSum

```
import torch

# specify the path to the saved checkpoint file
checkpoint_path = '~/Desktop/fyp/models/bert_transformer/model_step_44000.pt'
# load the checkpoint file
checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

can't load the model that trained using BERTSUM
This is what i find in the source code of how it is saved

```
    def _save(self, step):
        real_model = self.model
        # real_generator = (self.generator.module
        #                   if isinstance(self.generator, torch.nn.DataParallel)
        #                   else self.generator)

        model_state_dict = real_model.state_dict()
        # generator_state_dict = real_generator.state_dict()
        checkpoint = {
            'model': model_state_dict,
            # 'generator': generator_state_dict,
            'opt': self.args,
            'optim': self.optim,
        }
        checkpoint_path = os.path.join(self.args.model_path, 'model_step_%d.pt' % step)
        logger.info("Saving checkpoint %s" % checkpoint_path)
        # checkpoint_path = '%s_step_%d.pt' % (FLAGS.model_path, step)
        if (not os.path.exists(checkpoint_path)):
            torch.save(checkpoint, checkpoint_path)
            return checkpoint, checkpoint_path
```

can anyone help me ?

Is it because it is using it own optimizers in one of the file call optimizers.py in his file ?
If so how to solve it ?